# mysql, results varying when I add a column to the select

Tags: mysql

Mysql version:

```
'innodb_version', '5.7.33'
'protocol_version', '10'
'slave_type_conversions', ''
'tls_version', 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2'
'version', '5.7.33-log'
'version_comment', 'Source distribution'
'version_compile_machine', 'x86_64'
'version_compile_os', 'Linux'
```

I have something very odd going on with a production mysql database that I can not suss out & I may struggle to explain. When I copy the database over to somewhere else everything is fine.

There are 1.5 million rows in method_profile & so far this is the only row I know to have this issue.

The problem is displayed in two ways. 1) why do I get back an invalid id of '-2147476736' & why do I get no rows back when I ad deleted_timestamp to the SQL.

This first select returns a row as I expect:

```
select mp.id, mp.screening_profile_id, mp.deleted, mp.deleted_timestamp 
from method_profile mp
where mp.id = 481031;
```

[image: row returned as expected]

So then using the screening_profile_id value I run the following SQL:

```
select mp.id, mp.screening_profile_id, mp.deleted from method_profile mp
where mp.screening_profile_id = 420062  ;
```

[image: row returned with invalid id]

That id does not exist as shown by:

```
select mp.id from method_profile mp where mp.id = -2147476736;
```

[image: no row for invalid id]

If I change the second select to add another column 'mp.deleted_timestamp' I then get no row back at all:

```
select mp.id, mp.screening_profile_id, mp.deleted, mp.deleted_timestamp from method_profile mp
where mp.screening_profile_id = 420062  ;
```

[image: no row when deleted_timestamp is added to select]

The CREATE statement for the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `method_profile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '5.1',
  `primary_method_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondary_method_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instrument_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kit_code_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '5.1 - allow NULL as option see http://youtrack/issue/PTPORTAL2-100',
  `temperature_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(180) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slope` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '7.7',
  `intercept` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '7.7',
  `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `screening_profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `round_id_valid_from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `round_id_valid_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `measurement_unit_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instrument_ref` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `generated_primary_method_id` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`primary_method_id`,0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_secondary_method_id` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`secondary_method_id`,0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_instrument_id` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`instrument_id`,0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_instrument_ref` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`instrument_ref`,'')) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_round_id_valid_from` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`round_id_valid_from`,0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_round_id_valid_to` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`round_id_valid_to`,0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_kit_code_id` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`kit_code_id`,0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_temperature_id` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`temperature_id`,0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_name` varchar(180) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`name`,'')) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_slope` decimal(10,3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`slope`,0.0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_intercept` decimal(10,3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`intercept`,0.0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `generated_measurement_unit_id` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`measurement_unit_id`,0)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `inserted_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `generated_deleted_timestamp` timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(`deleted_timestamp`,'0000-00-00 00:00:00')) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `method_profile_instrument_ref_uniq_idx` (`screening_profile_id`,`generated_primary_method_id`,`generated_secondary_method_id`,`generated_instrument_id`,`generated_instrument_ref`,`generated_round_id_valid_from`,`generated_round_id_valid_to`,`generated_kit_code_id`,`generated_temperature_id`,`generated_name`,`generated_slope`,`generated_intercept`,`generated_measurement_unit_id`,`deleted`,`generated_deleted_timestamp`),
  KEY `fk_screening_profile_Kit_code1_idx` (`kit_code_id`),
  KEY `fk_screening_profile_temperature1_idx` (`temperature_id`),
  KEY `fk_screening_profile_method1_idx` (`primary_method_id`),
  KEY `fk_screening_profile_method2_idx` (`secondary_method_id`),
  KEY `fk_screening_profile_instrument1_idx` (`instrument_id`),
  KEY `fk_method_profile_screening_profile` (`screening_profile_id`),
  KEY `fk_method_profile_round_id_valid_from` (`round_id_valid_from`),
  KEY `fk_method_profile_round_id_valid_to` (`round_id_valid_to`),
  KEY `fk_method_profile_measurement_unit_id` (`measurement_unit_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_instrument` FOREIGN KEY (`instrument_id`) REFERENCES `instrument` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_kit_code` FOREIGN KEY (`kit_code_id`) REFERENCES `kit_code` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_measurement_unit_id` FOREIGN KEY (`measurement_unit_id`) REFERENCES `measurement_units` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_primary_method` FOREIGN KEY (`primary_method_id`) REFERENCES `method` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_round_id_valid_from` FOREIGN KEY (`round_id_valid_from`) REFERENCES `round` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_round_id_valid_to` FOREIGN KEY (`round_id_valid_to`) REFERENCES `round` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_screening_profile` FOREIGN KEY (`screening_profile_id`) REFERENCES `screening_profile` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_secondary_method` FOREIGN KEY (`secondary_method_id`) REFERENCES `method` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_method_profile_temperature` FOREIGN KEY (`temperature_id`) REFERENCES `temperature` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1614629 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: This number -2147476736 is hovering around the Max negative 32bit integer value. Which makes me think the integer max size is somehow getting involved here

Comment: I suspect it is something index, foreignkey related, but no idea. I tried running 'analyze table method_profile' & a couple of other linked tables with no change, other than the replica now shows the same issue when I 'think' it did not before

Comment: Not having any idea what has happened here & the issue appears to be linked to just this  one row. So I went for the bluderbus approach.  I inserted a new matching row, updated any FK tables to the new row, deleted the old 'broken' row & all now appears happy. very odd though